# When converting curl to python language

Tags: python, curl, encoding

I copied the curl data through an act like this:

[image]

I want to convert the below curl to python language. But The data in the form of a dictionary inside curl is wrapped in a strange form.**

The strange form of data looks like this:

```
--data-raw "^{^\^"common^\^":^{^\^"platform^\^":^\^"web^\^",^\^"pcid^\^":^\^"16185750214525097140297^\^",^\^"memberSrl^\^":^\^"^\^",^\^"libraryVersion^\^":^\^"1.3.0^\^",^\^"lang^\^":^\^"ko-KR^\^",^\^"resolution^\^":^\^"1536x864^\^",^\^"eventTime^\^":^\^"2021-05-12T05:40:15.119Z^\^",^\^"web^\^":^{^\^"pvid^\^":^\^"47b25d6b-2f7f-4edd-954e-6afb0413400e^\^",^\^"rvid^\^":^\^"^\^",^\^"url^\^":^\^"https://www.coupang.com/vp/products/281480779?vendorItemId=5246745661&sourceType=SDP_ALSO_VIEWED&rmdId=ed1666c1f69045658605a47bd3500ad9&eventLabel=recommendation_widget_pc_sdp_001&platform=web&rmdABTestInfo=10803:B,8534:A,12823:A,8088:A,8091:A,12574:C&rmdValue=p5269107492:vt-1.0.0:p281480779^\^",^\^"referrer^\^":^\^"https://www.coupang.com/vp/products/5269107492?itemId=7504683294&vendorItemId=74795528373&isAddedCart=^\^"^}^},^\^"meta^\^":^{^\^"schemaId^\^":238,^\^"schemaVersion^\^":27^},^\^"data^\^":^{^\^"productId^\^":281480779,^\^"vendorItemId^\^":5246745661,^\^"itemId^\^":893525515,^\^"sdpVisitKey^\^":^\^"tzygb7zra2s1johxcn^\^",^\^"domain^\^":^\^"sdp^\^",^\^"pageName^\^":^\^"recommendation^\^",^\^"eventName^\^":^\^"sdp_bottom_ads^\^",^\^"rmdValue^\^":^\^"p281480779:sdp_bottom_ads-1.0.0:p3443790,p281480779:sdp_bottom_ads-1.0.0:p1463163,p281480779:sdp_bottom_ads-1.0.0:p1413317797,p281480779:sdp_bottom_ads-1.0.0:p4753927275,p281480779:sdp_bottom_ads-1.0.0:p295539532,p281480779:sdp_bottom_ads-1.0.0:p1947426099,p281480779:sdp_bottom_ads-1.0.0:p1920685625,p281480779:sdp_bottom_ads-1.0.0:p1919127654,p281480779:sdp_bottom_ads-1.0.0:p1406557439,p281480779:sdp_bottom_ads-1.0.0:p4348160225,p281480779:sdp_bottom_ads-1.0.0:p1919127636,p281480779:sdp_bottom_ads-1.0.0:p324721177,p281480779:sdp_bottom_ads-1.0.0:p1661152176,p281480779:sdp_bottom_ads-1.0.0:p2207652674,p281480779:sdp_bottom_ads-1.0.0:p1318104835,p281480779:sdp_bottom_ads-1.0.0:p4541415097,p281480779:sdp_bottom_ads-1.0.0:p6120321,p281480779:sdp_bottom_ads-1.0.0:p200766309,p281480779:sdp_bottom_ads-1.0.0:p5301593450,p281480779:sdp_bottom_ads-1.0.0:p87794416^\^",^\^"feedsId^\^":^\^"02e6ae196d5b45bf93004ff3222a231d^\^",^\^"logType^\^":^\^"impression^\^",^\^"logCategory^\^":^\^"impression^\^"^},^\^"extra^\^":^{^\^"sentTime^\^":^\^"2021-05-12T05:40:15.119Z^\^"^},^\^"campaign^\^":^{^\^"src^\^":^\^"1042016^\^",^\^"spec^\^":^\^"10304903^\^",^\^"sid^\^":^\^"^\^",^\^"lptag^\^":^\^"^쿠^팡^\^",^\^"itime^\^":^\^"20210512143934^\^",^\^"ctag^\^":^\^"HOME^\^",^\^"appver^\^":^\^"^\^",^\^"addtag^\^":^\^"900^\^"^}^}"
```

I want to convert the data into a dictionary that can be processed in python.

I wonder why the data is in such an unusual form. Can you tell me how to transform the data into a normal form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The weirdness is almost certainly because `cmd` has unusual rules with regards to escaping characters. If you copy the `bash` variety of Curl command, it'll look nicer.

It'll also work in Curl-to-Python converters [such as this one](https://curl.trillworks.com/).